# Check if particular flag was sent to NSIS script

Tags: nsis, electron-builder

I'm trying to figure out if a `'/p'` flag was sent to my installer. I need to have my scripts react differently based on the following scenarios:

1. No flag sent
2. `'/p'` : flag sent, but no path after (blank path)
3. `'/p some_url'` : flag sent with an actual path

Basically, I need a way to find out if `'/p'` was even sent or not, then if it was, react in a certain way whether the following url is blank or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the docs for **$CMDLINE** variable: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#varother

You can parse this variable manually using (get parameters using **GetParameters**) and search for your desired parameter */p* and handle various cases.

Another method is to use **GetOptions**: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixE.html#getoptions which offers also parsing the parameters and their values (note, they use = to delimit name and value like /ADMIN=password).